# Calculate nearest hours to 00:00 in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

How can I calculate the nearest hours to midnight time `00:00` regardless of date in PHP. For example:

If time is `22:00` then `2` hours are required to reach `00:00`

If time is `04:00` then `-4` hours are the nearest to reach `00:00`

Currently I have the following PHP function:

```
<?php

$ts1 = strtotime('00:00');
$ts2 = strtotime('04:00');
$diff = ($ts1 - $ts2) / 3600;

?>
```

But this won't be helpful much in the above.

Comment: You can compare time objects in PHP with regular comparison operators: <,>

Comment: if you're only looking for hours (not minutes) could you not just do 24 - current hour (and just before check if current hour is below 12)?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the date (not only the time). This is because of daylight saving time changes. For example might 02:59 being closer to 00:00 then 21:01 on the time where daylight saving time will set back hour.

Comment: Isn't `3:00` **always** closer to `00:00`?

Comment: @PeeHaa Why? From 21:00 to 00:00 are regulary 3 hours, from 00:00 to 03:00 also 3 hours

Comment: ok I think I see what you are talking about. The question is whether OP wants 3:00 to return 2 or 3 when the clock goes one hour back

Comment: Yeah, but at 02:59 there is room for decision.

Comment: @PeeHaa sorry, meant *no* room for decision

Answer (score 1):

If you have the php [Datetime](http://php.net/manual/de/book.datetime.php) class available you can calculate the [difference](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.diff.php) between two DateTimes.

```
$time1 = new \DateTime('00:00');
$time2 = new \DateTime('04:00');

$diff = $time1->diff($time2, true);

$hourDifference = 0;
if ($diff->h < 12) {
    $hourDifference = -$diff->h;
} elseif ($diff->h > 12) {
    $hourDifference = 24 - $diff->h;
} else {
    $hourDifference = 12; // kann be positive or negative
}
```

And you'll get a [DateInverall](http://php.net/manual/de/class.dateinterval.php) object where you can access, hours, minuts, seconds and compare them with normal php operators.

Comment: Nope this won't work here. it's the same as my function. If you try to use '00:00' and '22:00'. You will get `22` hours difference while it should return `2`

Comment: What if you check, if the result is bigger than 12, than you have to subtract it from 24 to get the right value?

Comment: remember i need also the negative sign. So I need `-4` not just 4 in this case and if `22` then `2` and so on

Comment: in that case, if <12, store a flag to *-1 should do it

Comment: @Michael Samuel: updated my answer to fit your needs ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you'r not *too* interested in minutes;

**1. Extract minutes.**

- check if minutes is `>` or `<=30`
- if greater, 'store' 1

**2. Extract hour**

- check if hour is greater than 12
- if not, add 12 (store flag also to say it will be minus)

**3. if greater (ref. Step 1), add 1 to extracted hour.**

**4. 24 - extracted hour is your interval.**

---

Please note, this may be reduced/ simplified greatly.

Your interval (should) be correct to the nearest half hour